# Looping each split string data until finished

Tags: c#

I'm having a bit of a brain fart issue trying to decide the best way to approach this issue, my code is working fine, i just need to think of a way to add a small feature.

**Code:**

```
public async void SearchGoogle(string randomKeyword, bool debug) {

    // Ignore URLs containing these strings ...
    var ignore = File.ReadAllLines(@"LogicFiles\ignore.txt");

    // Google increments 10 at a time instead of 1 ...
    for (int x = 0; x <= 100; x+=10) {

        string url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + randomKeyword + "&client=firefox-b-d&channel=trow2&sxsrf=ALeKk0351-NMDQgTggMB6Vu6H7hNOQycpg:1590534216843&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:d&start=" + x + "&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_y_3X0dLpAhWqQhUIHcjtDeoQpwV6BAhtEBs&biw=1360&bih=654";

        webBrowser.Navigate(url);

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(webBrowser.DocumentText);

        if (debug)
        {
            Helpers.SaveDebugToFile(@"Debug\[google.com]-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmssffffff") + "-debug.html", webBrowser.DocumentText);
        }

        foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
        {
            HtmlAttribute href = link.Attributes["href"];
            if (ignore.Any(href.Value.Contains) || href.Value.Length < 5)
            {

            }
            else 
            {
                DataGridViewLinks.Rows.Add(href.Value.Trim(), randomKeyword, "");
            }
        }

        // Need a pause between page loads ...
        await SearchEngineDelay();

        // Update count ...
        UpdateLinksCount();

        // Update keyword ...
        UpdateKeywordBeingUsed(randomKeyword);

        // Remove duplicate links from the datagrid ...
        RemoveDuplicateRowsFromDataGridLinks();

    } // end for loop ...

    // Enable the button when finished ...
    BtnFindPotentialLinks.Enabled = true;

}
```

What the code above does is, it will take a random keyword from a string of keywords in a datagrid which is formatted like: `KEY1|KEY2|KEY3|etc` feed in that random keyword, then loop 10 pages, which works fine.

I'm now wanting it instead of selecting a random keyword, search each keyword 1 at a time instead of just selecting 1 random keyword, i'm not sure the best way to approach this, i know i would need to use: `string[] keywords = inputString.Split('|');` and somehow loop each keyword in the forloop but after this i'm not sure the best way.

Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't search these keywords in parallel (you need to delay between calls), then just iterate and search one at the time

```
foreach (var keyword in inputString.Split('|'))
{
    await SearchGoogle(keyword, false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you alex! i never thought of that, i now have a way :)